# Правильность ударения

Tags: орфоэпия

В разговорной речи встречается: не жлоби́сь и не жло́бись. Оба ли варианта можно считать верными?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верные формы указаны здесь:
[image]

Верная форма указана стрелочкой.

Порой можно услышать неофициальный вариант "не жлоби́сь", а "не жло́бись" режет слух (и даже очень), вместо него стоит употреблять "не жлобься" (указанный стрелочкой), в котором ударение тоже на О.

Comment: Наверно, лучше убрать из ответа "(разговорный)", достаточно указания "неофициальный", поскольку в Викисловаре и так уже обозначено, что слово разговорное.

Comment: Если обозначено, то да. А может, написать "просторечный"? Это как бы хуже, чем разговорный?

Comment: Более разговорный, чем изначальный вариант :))

Comment: Вообще, переходя на слово "жлоб", можно увидеть только просторечное, криминальное и жаргонное.

Comment: Ну, оно как обзывательство уже, скорее всего, поэтому.